# Rails not loading model.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I don't know why, but for some reason my nested association is not being respected by rails.

My student class has nested associations: addresses, tests

The addresses association works fine. The tests association, which is identical to the addresses association, does not work. While I can create and edit test instances successfully, they do not undergo the validation checks defined in their model, nor do they implement the ransack search features that I specified in their model.

Here's the student model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  unloadable

  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}

  has_many :addresses, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tests, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses,
    :reject_if => :all_blank,
    :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tests,
    :reject_if => :all_blank,
    :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Here's the addresses model (which works):

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  validates :address, presence: true, length: {maximum: 80}

def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    ['county', 'zip', 'address']
  end
end
```

And here's the (basically) identical tests model (which doesn't work):

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  validates :name, length: {maximum: 40}

  def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    ['score', 'date']
  end
end
```

It's completely ignoring the validation as well as the ransack function. While everything runs without error, I am able to input whatever I want, even if it's well over validated length, and it throws no error message.

I feel like I didn't create my model correctly or something, and Rails doesn't know it's there?

Comment: Please elaborate on *"does not work"*. For example: Is there an error message? What did you try, what did or did not happen?

Comment: See my edit, at the bottom I explain more detail.

Comment: I'm betting that you have __another__ model/class named Test in your application.

Comment: i don't think so...i actually have the name "student_test" in my model (it was changed from the old name, 'test'). so i doubt there'd be another model/class called 'student_test'

Comment: It does sound like it's treating `Test` specially.  You might be able to explore in console.  inspect the Test constant to see what you're creating.  Maybe a module from another library?

Answer (score 0):

`Test`, I believe is a module that in the `minitest` framework. Avoid naming your models `Test`. As a matter of fact `test` is a reserved keyword in Rails. Try renaming your model's name and trying again.